# What is Raleigh expansion?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, diffraction, plane-wave

I am currently reading the paper [*The dielectric lamellar diffraction grating*](https://mcgrating.com/references/ref05.pdf), in which the electric field above and bellow a 1D grating (grooves) is expressed as a "series of outward-going plane waves (Raleigh expansion)":

Above the grating:

$$E(x,y) = \sum_{p=-\infty}^{\infty}\Big[\exp(-i\chi_0 (y-h/2))\delta_{p0} + R_p \exp(\chi_p (y-h/2))\Big]\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\exp(i\alpha_px)$$

Bellow the grating:
$$E(x,y) = \sum_{p=-\infty}^{\infty}\Big[T_p \exp(-i\eta_0(y+h/2))\Big]\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\exp(i\alpha_px)$$

Can somebody please explain me this method, the Rayleigh expansion, or at least point me to some suitable reference? I failed to find anything comprehensible. Thank you very much.

Comment: See https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Class/phy319/phy319/node86.html

Comment: @my2cts Thanks for the link. However it does not derive the expansion, it just states it.

Comment: From thereon you can find what you are looking for. There's a wikipedia article as well.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave_expansion_method